# NinjectWebCommon implementation/translation - C# to F#

Tags: f#, ninject

I've translated this code from [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and would like it to be more idiomatic [f#](/questions/tagged/f%23):

```
namespace Foo.App_Start

open System
open System.Web

open Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper

open Ninject
open Ninject.Web.Common

type NinjectResolver(kernel:IKernel) =
    let _kernel = kernel
    interface System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver with 
        member this.BeginScope():Http.Dependencies.IDependencyScope = upcast this
        member this.GetService(t) =
            _kernel.TryGet(t)
        member this.GetServices(t)=
            _kernel.GetAll(t)
        member this.Dispose() = ()

//was static
[<AbstractClass; Sealed>]
type NinjectWebCommon () =
    static let bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper()

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
    //private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    static let RegisterServices(kernel:IKernel) =
        System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver <- new NinjectResolver(kernel)
        do()
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        //private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    static let KernelCreation(kernel:IKernel) =
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine "kernel Creation!"
        RegisterServices(kernel)
        let bs = fun () -> new Bootstrapper()
        let kernelFun= System.Func<IKernel> (fun () -> bs().Kernel)
        kernel.Bind<System.Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(fun ac -> kernelFun) |> ignore
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>() |> ignore
        let fetchedKernel:IKernel =System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof<IKernel>) :?> IKernel
        fetchedKernel

    static let CreateKernel():IKernel =
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine "standard kernel creating!"
        let kernel= new StandardKernel()  
//        
        try         //RegisterServices(kernel) |> ignore;
            KernelCreation(kernel)
        with
            | ex -> 
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine "kernel disposing!"
                kernel.Dispose()
                raise ex


    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the application
    /// </summary>
    static member Start() =
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule typedefof<OnePerRequestHttpModule> |> ignore
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule typedefof<NinjectHttpModule> |> ignore
        bootstrapper.Initialize(System.Func<_>(CreateKernel))
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine "app Start()"
//        
//        
    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the application.
    /// </summary>
    static member Stop() =
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine "app stop"
        bootstrapper.ShutDown()


module DummyModuleToAttachAssemblyAttribute = 
    [<assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof<NinjectWebCommon>, "Start")>]
    ////[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(FLochart.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]
    [<assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof<NinjectWebCommon>, "Stop")>]
    do()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems like it's primarily plumbing. There are no algorithms or types that could be given the functional treatment. I have only two recommendations.

1. Instead of `NinjectWebCommon` being abstract/sealed with static members you can make it a module with let-bound functions.
2. `_kernel` in `NinjectResolver` is unnecessary because primary constructor parameters are available throughout the body of the type. So you can just reference `kernel` throughout instead.